# Is there a UI widget that allows the user to select between two options (left or right)?

Tags: android

I need to implement a UI element that the user will use to select between two options (left and right).

Similar to a `seekbar`, but if the user drags all the way to one side or another, it will trigger an action depending which side was selected.  If the user lets go without touching either side, the thumb knob will bounce back to the center.

<strike>I think this is a common UI element but I can't seem to think of an example.</strike>

**EDIT:** A similar element would be the slider which is found on the iPhone lock screen.  In my case, the thumb knob would start in the middle and could be dragged in either direction.

Does anybody know of a library that might contain this, or will I need to extend the seekbar to implement it?

Comment: If it weren't for the "bounce back to the center" part, a `Switch` would fit your left/right part.

Comment: A `switch` doesn't have a neutral position that it defaults to before a selection is made.  I'm basically looking for a 3-way switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a subclass of a view and use onTouchEvent() and onDraw() to determine where the user is touching and draw the screen accordingly.

Comment: I think this is the way I'm going to go.  I haven't yet decided which class I want to subclass though.

Comment: I'd subclass a regular old View.

Comment: I ended up subclassing SeekBar - this provided me with a lot of functionality for free and it was relatively simple to modify it to get the behaviour I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Implement your own segment control like this:

[image]

Source code of this segment control is available in https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a library which contains such a UI element. As mentioned, the closest thing visually to what you want is a `Switch`, but I think the common way to implement the functionality you want is to use a `RadioGroup` or a `ListView`.

Comment: In my case the visual part is the important part :).